# Error while looping nested array of objects using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to display tasks array of object values(given below) using javascript. When I iterate through tasks array and render elements, it's okay. But I want to have loop inside outer loop to display sub tasks of each task. But, if I loop through each sub task as given below, then it throws error in the console as `task.subTasks.forEach(...) is not a function`

```
const tasks = [
  {
    id: 0,
    description: "task 1",
    subTasks: [
      { id: 0, description: "subtask 1" },
      { id: 1, description: "subtask 2" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    description: "task 2",
    subTasks: [
      { id: 0, description: "subtask 3" },
      { id: 1, description: "subtask 4" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "task 3",
    subTasks: [
      { id: 0, description: "sub task 5" },
      { id: 1, description: "sub task 6" },
    ],
  },
];

const accordion = document.querySelector("#accordion");

function displayTasks() {
  tasks.forEach((task, index) => {
    let html = `
        <div class="accordion-item" id="${index}">
            <div class="todo-task">
                <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
                <input value="${task.description}" placeholder="Update your task" type="text">
                <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                <a href="#${index}"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="todo-sub-tasks">
            `
            task.subTasks.forEach((item,index)=>{
                <div class="todo-sub-task">
                    <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
                    <input placeholder="Update your sub task" type="text" />
                    <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </div>
                
            })
            `
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
    accordion.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  });
}

displayTasks();
```

Comment: Please use `map()` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` does not return any value.

Comment: Yeah I have changed. Still throwing error.

Comment: Your `html` variable should be declared outside the `map()` call. You need to feed the result of the `map()` call to your `html` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `html` variable needs to be declared outside the loop call, so that you can feed the result of the loop into it.

An inner variable is used in the example below to compile the required HTML for each task.

```js
const tasks = [{
    id: 0,
    description: "task 1",
    subTasks: [
        { id: 0, description: "subtask 1" },
        { id: 1, description: "subtask 2" }
    ]
}, {
    id: 1,
    description: "task 2",
    subTasks: [
        { id: 0, description: "subtask 3" },
        { id: 1, description: "subtask 4" }
    ]
}, {
    id: 2,
    description: "task 3",
    subTasks: [
        { id: 0, description: "sub task 5" },
        { id: 1, description: "sub task 6" }
    ]
}];

const accordion = document.querySelector("#accordion");

function displayTasks() {
    const html = tasks.map((task, index) => {
        let taskHTML = `
            <div class="accordion-item" id="${index}">
                <div class="todo-task">
                    <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
                    <input value="${task.description}" placeholder="Update your task" type="text">
                    <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    <a href="#${index}"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="todo-sub-tasks">
        `;
        taskHTML += task.subTasks.map((subTask) => (`
                    <div class="todo-sub-task">
                        <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
                        <input value="${subTask.description}" placeholder="Update your sub task" type="text" />
                        <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                    </div>
        `));
        taskHTML += `
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
        return taskHTML;
    });
    accordion.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
}

displayTasks();
```

```html
<div id="accordion"></div>
```